# PHP sorting an array with uasort

Tags: php, sorting

So I sorted a multidimensional array with `uasort` in descending order. I did a `var_dump($winrateArray)` and it is sorted properly. The highest value is in the first returned array. However when I try a `var_dump($winrateArray[0][3])` which is where I expect the highest value to be it isn't there. Instead it is in `$winrateArray[1][3]`. Am I using `uasort` properly?

Unsorted dump:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "18" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(1) } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "31" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(100) [3]=> int(101) } }
```

Sorted dump:

```
array(2) { [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "31" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(100) [3]=> int(101) }  [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "18" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(1) } }
```

Specific dump:

```
int(1)
```

.

```
$winrateArray[0][0] = '18';
$winrateArray[0][1] = '1';
$winrateArray[0][2] = 0;
$winrateArray[0][3] = 1;

$winrateArray[1][0] = '31';
$winrateArray[1][1] = '1'
$winrateArray[1][2] = 100;
$winrateArray[1][3] = 101;

var_dump($winrateArray);

function cmp($a, $b){
        if ($a[3] == $b[3]){
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a[3] < $b[3]) ? 1 : -1;
    }

uasort($winrateArray, 'cmp');

var_dump($winrateArray);
var_dump($winrateArray[0][3]);
```

Comment: post an example set of the data you are using, it will be much for us to help and test.

Comment: We need to see the array and the results.

Comment: As I see the result is ordered properly but the keys are preserved and you don't  want that?

Comment: I added some data and showed the results of the dumps. To be honest I think I'm just misinterpreting how this sort works. I thought it would move the highest value to [0][3], 2nd highest to [1][3].

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that

Comment: I do want to preserve the keys I think I just don't understand how to use them properly.

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: You want to simply exchange `uasort()` with `usort()`, since you don't want to preserve the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$newArray = $winrateArray;
uasort($winrateArray, 'cmp');

$i = 0;
foreach($winrateArray as $key => $item) {
     $newArray[$i][3] = $item[3];
     $i++;
}
```

and use the new array after that. You will preserve keys and you will reorder  and replace 3rd elements only

Comment: That solution works perfectly. I don't fully understand what "as $key => $item" is doing but thanks a lot!

Comment: $key is the key of the current item in the foreach loop (parent keys) and item holds the inner array (the array with 3 elements) of given parent.